# UDF not being parallelized on pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have data that I am trying to build a tree model on. The dataset is 6 million row
I'm using pandas udf successfully to train multiple Lightgbm models with on multiple nodes

Using Databricks with the following configuration

```
worker type: r5.24xlarge
Driver type: r5.24xlarge
Max workers: 12
```

Since pandas udf, supposedly, does the computing in parallel for each group, I thought that I could finish the training faster by using a cluster with more workers.

checking the Stage Detail page on the Web UI ,I see that I have only one stage responsible for the udf pandas training. It took 4 hours. Acessing the details of this stage, I see it had only one task, with {'Locality Level': 'PROCESS_LOCAL'}, that took the whole 4 hours. Screenshots below.

My assumption is the training is not being parallelized. I have attached the code below but I am not able to point where the mistake is

```
#reading data into pandas dataframe
train_gbm_x = s3_read_csv()
train_gbm_original = train_gbm_x.copy()

#create replicas of the dataset so that I can run 4 versions of these in parallel
for i in range(1,5,1):
  x_t_c = train_gbm_x.copy()
  x_t_c['id']=i
  print(train_gbm_x_original.shape)
  train_gbm_x_original =train_gbm_x_original.append([x_t_c], ignore_index=True) 

train_gbm_sp = spark.createDataFrame(train_gbm_x_original) #convert to spark dataframe

# main UDF
schema = StructType([
                     StructField('r_squared', DoubleType(), True)])  

@f.pandas_udf(schema, f.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def train_RF(data):
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
    import numpy as np
    import lightgbm as lgb
#     params_xgb['objective'] = 'binary:logistic'
    
    import xgboost as xgb
    xgb_model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(bagging_fraction=0.9500000000000001, boosting_type='goss',
               feature_fraction=0.53, learning_rate=0.045075773005757123,
               max_depth=2, metric='binary_logloss', min_child_samples=70,
               min_child_weight=0, min_data_in_bin=54, min_data_in_leaf=219,
               min_gain_to_split=0.75, n_estimators=9900, num_leaves=1000,
               objective='binary', random_state=4, reg_alpha=7.906971438083483,
               reg_lambda=9.905206242985752, verbosity=-1)

    
        
    # create data and label groups 
    y_train = data['label']
    X_train = data.drop(['employee_id', 'date','label'], axis=1)
    xgb_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    # make predictions
    y_pred = xgb_model.predict(X_train)
    r = pearsonr(y_pred, y_train)
    print(y_pred)
    
    # return the number of trees, and the R value 
    return pd.DataFrame({'r_squared': (r[0]**2)}, index=[0])
```

The call to the UDF is as follows:

```
train_gbm_sp= train_gbm_sp.sort(F.col("emp_id"),F.col("id"))
model_coeffs_r =train_gbm_sp.groupby('id').apply(train_RF)
model_coeffs_r.show(5)
```

spark UI screenshot:
[image]

This view shows that it is being run on a single executor ID
[image]

I am not sure where the exact issue is, if someone can help point to what I might be doing wrong in the set up here.

Thank you

Comment: this is something to do with spark.python.worker.reuse property, check this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26549

Comment: udf does not get parallelized

Comment: @thebluephantom Is there some other way for me to run this pandas function in parallel other than UDF's ( I was following this tutorial https://databricks.com/blog/2020/05/19/manage-and-scale-machine-learning-models-for-iot-devices.html )

Comment: Not a pandas expert.

Comment: Seems you need a repartition. Reading data like this should cause all your data situated in a single node.

Comment: did you have the above problem? I am having the same issue.